# How to prevent WinForms TabPage from flicker?

Tags: c#, winforms

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/double-buffered-graphics?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) suggests to use the DoubleBuffered property, but the property is protected and cannot be set without subclassing a Control.

I've successfully used DoubleBuffered to prevent the Form from flicker, without DoubleBuffered set to true, the Form will flicker when redrawn at high rate.

But TabPage is used by TabControl internally and TabControl doesn't provide a factory interface for tab pages.

Is there simple way to do the subclassing, or is there other methods?

Comment: TabControl surfaces a TabPages property where you can add a derived TabPage. If it helps to reduce flicker i don't know. You may try.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16925369/2596334) here.

Comment: @dr.null It doesn't work.

Comment: @Ralf It works, I'v post an answer

Comment: Yes, it's too late in `TabControl.ControlAdded`. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Manually modify Form1.Designer.cs:

```
...
this.tabImage = new DictTool.NFTabPage();
...
private NFTabPage tabImage;
...
```

Add new class:

```
NFPage.cs:

    public class NFTabPage : TabPage
    {
        public NFTabPage() : base() { DoubleBuffered = true; }                       
    }
```